# Write tests with $q.all() in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I am very new to Jasmine.
I have tried to write the test case for the following code scenario but the test fails.
The spy written for service call is working fine, but I'm not able to write test case with `$q.all()`.

```
 function getUserDetails() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promises = [];

            vm.method = 'GetUserDetailsEx';
            var data = {
                sessionVal: "sdadfad8787",  Username:"test",UserId:1,AdditionalInput: null
            };
            vm.fetchUsers();

            var fetchUserDs = vm.fetchUsers();
            promises.push(fetchUserDs );

        $q.all(promises).then(function () {
            if (getUserDetailsResponse.ResultCode == 0) {});


    }
}

it('should fetch User Details to be defined', function () {
       myTestController.getUserDetails();
       scope.$digest();
       expect(myTestController.getUserDetails).toBeDefined();
       it('should resolve promise', function () {
     myTestController.$q.all(myTestController.fetchUserDetails).then(function     () {
});
       scope.apply();
     }
```

Comment: Fails how? What is the returned message?

Comment: @Darren Sweeney it executes the code,but in the code coverage fails to cover the code.kindly help me